# Element could not be located on page. In selenium python winapp driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium, winappdriver

When I execute the code, I receive the message: "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters" and automation id is not showing in inspection tool so I am using name element here but name element not fetching.

My code

```
def test_initialize(self):

time.sleep(15)

string ="Create Project ... "

rawstring=r"{}".format(string)

self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, rawstring).click()
```

My error output from webdriver console

```
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723

User-Agent: appium/python 2.2.0 (selenium/4.1.0 (python windows))

{"using": "class name", "value": "Create Project \u2026"}

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Content-Length: 139

Content-Type: application/json

{"status":7,"value":{"error":"no such element", "message": "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."}
```

Why this error is coming could you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Get element like `<xxx>Create Project ... </xxx>` with

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Create Project ... ')]")
```

---

Get element like `<div name = "Create Project ...">xxx</div>` with

```py
driver.find_element(By.NAME, rawstring)
```

---

Get element like `<name>xxx</name> "` with

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "name")
```

---

Maybe you want first one ?

Comment: getting i tried the above one but same issue `{"using": "xpath", "value": "//*[contains(text(), 'Create Project \u2026')]"} ` it not able to identify or locate `'Create Project ... '` this element

Comment: @Deepak Then I need more detail information to answer correctly. Copy the element, at least opening tag, and paste here.

Comment: `How found: Mouse move (912,561)
 hwnd=0x0000000000200CC0 64bit class="Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND" style=0x56300000 ex=0x20Name: "Create Project …"
ControlType: UIA_ButtonControlTypeId (0xC350)
LocalizedControlType: "button"
BoundingRectangle: {l:741 t:537 r:1179 b:583}
IsEnabled: true
IsOffscreen: false
IsKeyboardFocusable: true
HasKeyboardFocus: false
AccessKey: ""
ProcessId: 16860
RuntimeId: [2A.200CC0.4.FFFFFFCF]
FrameworkId: "Chrome"
IsControlElement: true
ProviderDescription: "[pid:16860,providerId:0x0 Main(parent link):Microsoft: 
`

Comment: idk what it shows. we need element. use dev tools to find element and get it.